# Getting Weather data for All locations in US in python

Tags: python, weather-api, weatherdata

Hello I have a code but it gives only weather data for one location how to loop it for all locations in USA. Below is my code. I have written two locations. Is it possible to read from file and get the data of all locations in USA.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

def getWeatherForecast():
   now = datetime.now()
   startdate = (datetime.now() - timedelta(2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   enddate = (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   LOCATION = ["Texas","California"]
   for i in LOCATION:
       requestUrl = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/"+i+"/"+startdate+"/"+enddate+"?unitGroup=metric&include=days&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&contentType=json"
       print('Weather requestUrl={requestUrl}'.format(requestUrl=requestUrl))
       req = urllib.request.urlopen(requestUrl)
       rawForecastData = req.read()
       req.close()
       d = json.loads(rawForecastData)
   return d

def weather():
   weatherForecast = getWeatherForecast()
   print('Weather forecast for {location}'.format(location=weatherForecast['resolvedAddress']))
   days = weatherForecast['days'];
   for day in days:
       print('{datetime} tempmax:{tempmax} tempmin:{tempmin} description:{description}'.format(datetime=day['datetime'],
                                                                                               tempmax=day["tempmax"],
                                                                                               tempmin=day["tempmin"],
                                                                                               description=day[
                                                                                                   "description"]))
       df = pd.DataFrame(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the all location in the USA and converted to a list. Maybe you can use like this. I put all requests into `try/except` method and time sleep 5 seconds to prevent error. Maybe you should read the all documentations about this API. I've just found these : https://www.visualcrossing.com/resources/documentation/weather-api/timeline-weather-api/

```
def getWeatherForecast():
   now = datetime.now()
   startdate = (datetime.now() - timedelta(2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   enddate = (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   LOCATION =  ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut",
     "Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa",
     "Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan",
     "Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire",
     "New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio",
     "Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina",
     "South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia",
     "Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]
   try:
       for i in LOCATION:
           requestUrl = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/"+i+"/"+startdate+"/"+enddate+"?unitGroup=metric&include=days&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&contentType=json"
           print('Weather requestUrl={requestUrl}'.format(requestUrl=requestUrl))
           req = urllib.request.urlopen(requestUrl)
           rawForecastData = req.read()
           req.close()
           d = json.loads(rawForecastData)
           time.sleep(5)
   except:
      pass
   return d
```